# Counting elements for different string sets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1':['apple; kiwi; banana','orange; apple','apple', 'apple, orange, melon']}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

to get :

```
                   col1
0   apple; kiwi; banana
1         orange; apple
2                 apple
3  apple, orange, melon
```

I want to count how many times `apple` comes in association with other fruits. If I do `df.value_counts()` I can see that each element is counted once only. I would want to know however how times `apple` are in coming in different cell length, as in `apple` has two cells that have 3 string, 1 cell with 2 string and 1 cell in 1 string. So the outcome would be:

```
   len of string  number for apple
0              1                 1
1              2                 1
2              3                 2
```

Comment: How is the number of apples 2 in third row?

Comment: we have 2 entries of length 3 namely 'apple; kiwi; banana' and 'apple, orange, melon'

Comment: where there is apple in them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter columns with `apple`s, then count `;` and add `1` for number of values separated by `;` and for count use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df[df['col1'].str.contains('apple')]
df1= (df['col1'].str.replace(',',';')
                .str.count(';')
                .add(1)
                .value_counts(sort=False)
                .rename_axis('vals')
                .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   vals  count
0     1      1
1     2      1
2     3      2
```

Comment: Can you explain why do need to use `add(1)`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Because I count `;` - it means for count of values is added `+1`